# ¿Cómo combinar dos barplots independientes en unos solo?

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando con dos `dataframes` con las mismas columnas pero distinto número de filas.

```
# Cargar datos
post_sc <- read.csv("post_sc.csv", sep = ";"); post_nc <- read.csv("post_nc.csv", sep = ";")
# Incluir niveles
f1 <- factor(post_sc$Q3, levels = c("0 to 5", "6 to 11", "12 to 17", "18 to 22", "23 to 28", "29 to 32", "more than 33"))
f2 <- factor(post_nc$Q3, levels = c("0 to 5", "6 to 11", "12 to 17", "18 to 22", "23 to 28", "29 to 32", "more than 33"))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
barplot(table(f1), ylab= "Students", main="YC: index number", cex.names=1.2, cex.axis=1.2, ylim=c(0,13), col="lightgreen")  
barplot(table(f2), ylab= "Students", main="NC: index number", cex.names=1.2, cex.axis=1.2, ylim=c(0,13), col="lightblue")
```

Me gustaría saber si es posible unificar ambos barplots en uno solo, aun  trabajando con factores de diferente longitud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, veamos un poco tu ejemplo, no tengo forma de reproducirlo exactamente, pero creo que podría ser algo así:

```
set.seed(100)
levels <- c("0 to 5", "6 to 11", "12 to 17", "18 to 22", "23 to 28", "29 to 32", "more than 33")
post_sc <- data.frame(Q3=sample(levels, 1000, replace=T, prob = c(.2,.1,.1,.3,.1,.1,.1)))
post_nc <- data.frame(Q3=sample(levels, 100, replace=T, prob = c(.1,.2,.2,.1,.2,.1,.1)))

f1 <- factor(post_sc$Q3, levels = levels)
f2 <- factor(post_nc$Q3, levels = levels)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
barplot( table(f1), ylab= "Students", main="YC: index number (post_sc)", cex.names=.8, cex.axis=1.2, col="lightgreen")
barplot( table(f2), ylab= "Students", main="YC: index number (post_nc)", cex.names=.8, cex.axis=1.2, col="lightblue")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar en el eje Y, los dos `data.frames` tienen distintas cantidades de observaciones , uno en particular tiene 10 veces menos observaciones que el otro. Sin embargo las dos variables se corresponden al mismo factor. Para mostrar ambos gráficos en uno solo y de paso contextualizar las escalas de ambos, podrías transformar los dos factores en una matriz y graficar esta. Por ejemplo:

```
# Convertimos los dos factores en columnas d euna matriz
mat <- cbind(as.matrix(table(f1)), 
             as.matrix(table(f2)))
#Agregamos los nombres de columnas
colnames(mat) <- c("post_sc", "post_nc")

barplot( mat, 
         beside=TRUE, 
         ylab="Students", 
         main="YC: index number",
         legend.text = rownames(mat)
         )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto Patricio, desconocía el uso de matrices para estos casos. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Una alternativa usando `tidyverse`: unir "verticalmente" (i.e., por filas) los dos data.frame y generar los dos gráficos usando paneles con `facet_wrap()`.

## En limpio

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(post_nc = post_nc, post_sc = post_sc, .id = "id") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Q3)) +
    geom_bar() + 
    facet_wrap(~id) + 
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
    labs(title = "YC: index number", y = "Students")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Con comentarios

```
library(tidyverse)  #Importa ggplot2 y dplyr para bind_rows()

# Une los dos data.frame, agrega la columna id en la que se repite el nombre del data.frame de origen
bind_rows(post_nc = post_nc, #Los nombres que asigno aquí serán los nombres de cada panel en el gráfico final
          post_sc = post_sc, 
          .id = "id") %>%     #Nombre arbitrario de la columna con la info del data.frame de origen
  ggplot(aes(x = Q3)) +
    geom_bar() +             #stat_bar() internamente hace los conteos
    facet_wrap(~id) +        #Un panel para cada categoría de id. scales = "free" para que cada panel se escale en su propio rango (replicando el comportamiento de par (mfrow = c(2,1))
#Hasta esta línea es lo mínimo necesario, lo que sigue es estética para mejorar el gráfico
    theme_minimal() +                                              #No me gusta el fondo gris.
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +     #Roto las etiquetas por legibilidad
    labs(title = "YC: index number", 
           y = "Students")
```

Personalmente encuentro más elegantes desde lo visual a los gráficos de barras de R Base. De todos modos el mecanismo de `facet_wrap()` de ggplot2 es muy potente y soluciona fácilmente muchos problemas como este y aún más complejos.